# Using a multi-region S3 accesspoint with sagemaker (terraform)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-sagemaker

I have a sagemaker model that will be deployed in different aws regions. This model will download models from an s3 bucket that is in region x. As long as the model is deployed in region x, the endpoint works.
However, when I deploy the sagemaker model from region y, it fails with the message.

> Error: error creating SageMaker model: ValidationException: Could not
> access model data at s3://mmmm/. Please ensure that the role
> "arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/dev-xxx-iam-role" exists and that its trust
> relationship policy allows the action "sts:AssumeRole" for the service
> principal "sagemaker.amazonaws.com". Also ensure that the role has
> "s3:GetObject" permissions and that the object is located in region x.

My iam role permissions are as follows:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "sm_full_access_attach" {
  name       = "sm-full-access-attachment"
  roles      = [aws_iam_role.sagemaker_inferencer_iam_role.name]
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSageMakerFullAccess"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "s3_full_access_attach" {
  name       = "s3-full-access-attachment"
  roles      = [aws_iam_role.sagemaker_inferencer_iam_role.name]
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"
}
```

with the assume role policy of:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sm_assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["sagemaker.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}
```

The iam role is as follows:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "sagemaker_inferencer_iam_role" {
  name               = "${var.app_environment}-inferencer-sm-${var.aws_region}-iam-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sm_assume_role_policy.json
}
```

And the above works for same region buckets.

I can of course create have buckets in each region with replication rules from the original bucket. However, this is costly as the model files are huge. So I created a multi-region accesspoint for my original bucket with an alias zzz.mrap

However, when I specify the accesspoint alias in the aws_sagemaker_model resource as follows:

```
resource "aws_sagemaker_model" "sagemaker_multimodel" {
  name               = "${var.app_environment}-inferencer-sm-${var.aws_region}-model"
  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.sagemaker_inferencer_iam_role.arn

  primary_container {
    image          = local.multi_model_inferencer_container_name
    mode           = "MultiModel"
    model_data_url = "s3://zzz.mrap/"
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Error: error creating SageMaker model: ValidationException: Could not
> access model data at s3://zzzz.mrap/. Please ensure that the role
> "arn:aws:iam::878435376106:role/dev-xxx-iam-role" exists and that its
> trust relationship policy allows the action "sts:AssumeRole" for the
> service principal "sagemaker.amazonaws.com". Also ensure that the role
> has "s3:GetObject" permissions and that the object is located in
> region x.

[AWS says](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/MultiRegionAccessPoints.html) that I only have to replace the bucket name by the alias and that they support sagemaker, however this does not seem to be the case.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So `"arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/dev-xxx-iam-role"` exists and it has a trust policy which has `sts:AssumeRole`?

Comment: yes, i just added this to the question, thanks

Comment: Can you add the `dev-xxx-iam-role` to the question as well?

Comment: It is added now :)

Comment: Ah, well, I think SageMaker assumes another role when you are running it (in the background). So you probably want to allow that role to assume the second role, i.e., the policy document should allow that role instead of `identifiers = ["sagemaker.amazonaws.com"]`.

Comment: Is there anyway to find what this role is (eg: by looking at the console, or can I put identifiers = ["*"] ?

Comment: From the docs: `Under Notebook > Notebook instances, select the notebook. The ARN is given in the Permissions and encryption section.`.

Comment: actuallly this is not a notebook, it is an inference endpoint

Comment: @toing_toing did u get this to work ? i use a MRAP and it is constntly throwing error "ClientError: An error occurred (InternalFailure) when calling the CreateModel operation (reached max retries: 4):"